# cumulative output as if with name

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
class Cummulative {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arrayValue[] ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};

        String arrayAlpha[] ={"A","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","X","Y","Z"};

        String newArray[] = {"R","A","G","H","U"};

        int total=0;

        for (int i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<arrayAlpha.length; j++) {
                if (arrayAlpha[j].equals(arrayValue[i])) {
                    total = total+arrayValue[j];
                    System.out.println(newArray[i]+"  "+arrayValue[j]+" "+total);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output should have the following format:

```
A 0 1
B 1 2
c 3 5
D 6 10
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<arrayAlpha.length;j++)
{

Comment: format proper code, it would help in visibility

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you need to replace arrayValue with newArray in your if statement.

Comment: my code is not working properly it doesnt show any value the first left hand side Must display Name RAGHU  and later step must be in actual letter values and final right hand side must show cummilative addition values

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: `if (arrayAlpha[j].equals(arrayValue[i]))`

It should be if `(arrayAlpha[j].equals(newArray[i]))`.

Sidenote: Using this code "A" will return 0. It seems like this is not desired, so I removed the first value from both `arrayAlpha` and `arrayValue`.

```
class Cummulative {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arrayValue[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};

        String arrayAlpha[] ={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","X","Y","Z"};

        String newArray[] = {"R","A","G","H","U"};

        int total=0;

        for (int i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<arrayAlpha.length; j++) {
                if (arrayAlpha[j].equals(newArray[i])) {
                    total += arrayValue[j];
                    System.out.println(newArray[i]+"  "+arrayValue[j]+" "+total);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alex no problem! Please consider hitting the grey checkmark beside my answer :)